# How do I format a number using jstl format tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a jsp page in which i need to display a number in this format.

original number : 1234567890
Formatted number : 123-456-7890

How can we accomplish this using jstl fmt tag?

To be precise what should be the value of the pattern attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to format like a phone number?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need your custom tag to do that (it can still wrap `NumberFormat`). You can use

```
<fmt:formatNumber value=".." groupingUsed="true" />
```

To enable grouping, but the grouping separator will depend on the locale

Answer (score 0):

You can look into something like this for your tag library implementation. It's from NetUI library

```
<netui:span value="2125555555">
        <netui:formatString pattern="phone (###) ###-####"/>
</netui:span>
```

[javadoc](http://beehive.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/netui/apidocs/javadoc/org/apache/beehive/netui/tags/html/FormatString.html)  , [source](http://www.koders.com/java/fid6ECD1E0A3FBE6EF1998C40576C8E83F2D9C832F5.aspx?s=netui%20formatString#L19)